# checking if a Couchbase node is down

Tags: java, couchbase

i am working with Couchbase server 2.5.1 and the java client.

the Couchbase auto fail-over happens after 30 seconds and Couchbase can only auto fail-over one node until you reset the fail-over counter.
because of this limitations i need to develop my own fail over mechanism.
i found all the rest commands the allow me to choose a node and fail-over it.
now i need to find a way to identify if a chosen node is down.

has any one faced this problem?
does any one has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long search, i found no official answer to my question.
as a result my solution will be to access each node using the Rest API,
in case there was no response with in a pre defined time the node will be automatically failed -over using the nodes REST API.